# Pass options to the builtin svgo from svgr/webpack

Tags: svg, webpack, svgo

Is there an option to pass in svgo options to the svgr/webpack loader ? I want to remove the width & height attributes and keep the viewbox, by default it removes those.

```js
{
    test: /\.svg$/,
    use: ['@svgr/webpack'],
    options : {
    svgo: { // Something like this ?
        mergePaths: false,
        removeViewbox: false,
        removeAttrs: true,
    }}

},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find a way of passing arguments through svgr to svgo so I switched to `react-svg-loader` which has documentation on how to achieve that :

```js
{
    test: /\.svg$/,
    use: [
        'babel-loader',
        {
            loader: 'react-svg-loader',
            options: {
                svgo: {
                    plugins: [{ removeDimensions: true, removeViewBox: false }],
                    floatPrecision: 2,
                },
            },
        },
    ],
},
```

Answer (score 21):

In my case I got errors that:

1. `plugins` should be an array;
2. Each plugin object requires a `name` property

So here is what worked for me:

```
use: {
 loader: '@svgr/webpack',
 options: {
  svgoConfig: {
   plugins: [
    {
      name: 'removeViewBox',
      active: false
    }
   ]
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: How to pass options into plugin?

Comment: Each property in the objects inside the `plugins` array is an option for the given plugin. In the snippet above `name` is the name of the plugin for `svgr` and `active` is an option.

Comment: This was helpful! Thanks very much!

Answer (score 7):

I've ran into this today, [@dimitar-spassov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12575508/dimitar-spassov)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70360615/10956001) seemed promising, however something might have changed since, because the viewBox was still removed.

The mentioned passing options to svgo is still correct, as mentioned [here](https://react-svgr.com/docs/options/#svgo-config).

I found the proper configuration for svgo [here](https://github.com/svg/svgo/issues/1128#issuecomment-1367070568).

All in all, what worked for me looks like this:

```
{
  test: /\.svg$/,
  use: [
    {
      loader: '@svgr/webpack',
      options: {
        svgoConfig: {
          plugins: [
            {
              name: 'preset-default',
              params: {
                overrides: {
                  removeViewBox: false
                },
              },
            },
          ]
        }
      }
    },
  ],
}
```

Comment: I upvoted it and an hour later noticed that this fixes one thing and breaks something else :(

Comment: @szym what did it break? It might broke it for me too, I just haven't noticed?

Comment: I finally found the issue. I had id collisions and on some pages instead of couple different SVGs i saw the same one couple of times. I've added 'prefixIds' at the end of the plugins array and that fixed it for me. If you don't pass any configuration to svgo then prefixIds is active but once you add the above it stops working. Not sure why.

Comment: Awesome, works, as far as I understand it keeps optimization?

Answer (score 3):

https://react-svgr.com/docs/options/

the answer is as

```
{
  loader: "@svgr/webpack",
  options: {
    dimensions: false
  }
},
```

Answer (score 1):

It has a little confusing syntax with nested parameters. Here is what I'm using to disable prefixing ids and classnames. I suppose, in your case it will be something like `mergePaths.active = false`, `removeViewbox.active = false`.

```
loader: '@svgr/webpack',
    options: {
        svgoConfig: {
            plugins: [{
                prefixIds: {
                    prefixIds: false,
                    prefixClassNames: false
                }
            }]
     }
}
```

I did not test, but I suppose it would look like this (or similar, you might play with it a bit to get the syntax right):

```
loader: '@svgr/webpack',
    options: {
        svgoConfig: {
            plugins: [{
                removePaths: {
                    active: false,
                }
            },{
                removeViewbox: {
                    active: false,
                }
            },{
                removeAttrs: {
                    active: true,
                }
            }]
     }
}
```

Look into the code here, where you can figure out what props are actually being exported: https://github.com/svg/svgo

Comment: I just switched of svgr because  there is no documentation whatsoever on how to pass arguments to svgo. `react-svg-loader` on the other hand has documentation and works the same way, so I would recommend people use that

Comment: I think the doco for the `svgr` is quite well, just need to play with it. You have to consider that it is free and open source and thus the author is doing it in his/her free time. I was looking at `react-svg-loader` too when making the decision, but `svgr` simply worked better for me. But it's true that I had to figure out a few things from the code as they were not described in detail in the doco.

Answer (score 0):

It works as described [here](https://github.com/svg/svgo/issues/439) or [here](https://github.com/svg/svgo/blob/master/docs/how-it-works/en.md#how-it-works):

```
{
  test: /\.svg$/,
  use: [{
    loader: '@svgr/webpack',
    options: { 
      svgoConfig: {
        plugins: [
          { mergePaths: false },
          { removeViewbox: false },
          { removeAttrs: true },
        ],
      },
    },
  }],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add configuration for svgo:

```
options: {
            svgoConfig: {
              plugins: {
                removeViewBox: false
              }
            }
          }
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score 0):

This option can help too

```
  {
    test: /\.svg$/,
    use: [
      {
        loader: '@svgr/webpack',
        options: {
          icon: true
        },
      }
    ],
```

Answer (score -1):

**If you are using Next.js, please follow these steps to configure SVG optimization:**

1. In the root directory of your Next.js project, create a file called `svgo.config.js` with following content.

   ```js
   // svgo.config.js
   module.exports = {
     plugins: [
       {
         name: 'preset-default',
         params: {
           overrides: {
             removeViewBox: false,
             // Customize default plugin options here if needed
           },
         },
       },
     ],
   };
   ```
2. Open your terminal and run the development server for your Next.js project using the following command:

   ```
   npm run dev
   ```
3. While your development server is running, visit your application in a web browser, and any SVG images should now have their `viewBox` attribute preserved.
4. If this solution helped you, consider upvoting to help the Next.js Users.