# How to disable auto prefixing class names in svgoConfig of @svgr webpack?

Tags: reactjs, svg, webpack

@svgr/webpack (https://react-svgr.com/docs/webpack/) is changing the name of classes in svg, by prefixing them, for example class `circle` is changed to `spinner-svg__circle`.

I have already tried the below two options to disable that behaviour, but none of them worked:

1. source: https://github.com/gregberge/svgr/issues/411 and https://github.com/gregberge/svgr/pull/412/files

   ```
        {
          test: /\.svg$/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: '@svgr/webpack',
              options: {
                svgoConfig: {
                  plugins: [{ prefixIds: false }]
                }
              }
            },'url-loader'
          ]
        }
   ```
2. the below one I found here: [Pass options to the builtin svgo from svgr/webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64376001/pass-options-to-the-builtin-svgo-from-svgr-webpack)

   ```
           svgoConfig: {
              plugins: [
                {
                  prefixIds: {
                    prefixIds: false,
                    prefixClassNames: false
                  }

                }
              ]
            }
   ```
3. source: https://github.com/gregberge/svgr/issues/400

   ```
            svgoConfig: {
              plugins: [
                {
                  prefixIds: {
                    prefix: false
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
   ```

Is there any other way to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

So the 2) option works - I couldn't get it working because there was a separate webpack config file for a storybook (where I tested effects), and I instead of applying changes there, I applied them to the main webpack config file of the project.